# Refresh control does not work for my TableViewController

Tags: xcode, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have a `TableViewController` that I instantiate by code with the following line:

```
let myTableVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableViewController") as! MyTableViewController
```

I have also enabled the `Refreshing` option for the TableViewController in the Attributes inspector. But I guess that does not make sense if I instantiate the TableViewController by code and not as, for example, a segue (by Control-dragging the objects in the Main storyboard in XCode), because when I access MyTableViewController through a segue, the `refreshControl` works! But it does not work if I instantiate it as above with code!

If I print the refreshContol object I instantiate with code I get this output if that helps:

```
Optional(<UIRefreshControl: 0x13cd67550; frame = (0 0; 600 60); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x13cd6b390>>)
```

EDIT:
Ok, in my initial ViewController I have this code:

```
let myTableVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableViewController") as! MyTableViewController

self.addChildViewController(myTableVC)
self.scrollView.addSubview(myTableVC.view)
myTableVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

The MyTableViewController class itself looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.refreshControl?.enabled = true
        self.refreshControl?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        print("MyTableViewController",self.refreshControl!, self.refreshControl?.enabled)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
        // Code to refresh table view
        print("Refresing contents...")

        self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
    }   
}
```

As you can see it is very simple, but the refreshing does not work!

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Particularly your refreshControl handler etc